# Too many redirect errors ONLY on Wordpress admin panel after updating PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404, wordpress-admin

I am working on updating a site. Everything was going peachy until I updated the PHP from 5.6 to 7.0+. Once I did that, I got the "Too many redirects" error ONLY on my Wordpress admin panel. The site itself loads fine and I can get the admin panel to show back up by setting the php back to 5.6.  So far I have tried: 
1: Clearing browser data (Has it ever been that easy?)
2: Disabling all plugins 
3: Adding:

```
define(‘WP_HOME’,’http://dontredirect.com’);

define(‘WP_SITEURL’,’http://dontredirect.com’);
```

and other variations of this code in the wp-config file.
I'm wondering if anyone out there has experienced a similar issue and how they resolved it.
 Thanks!

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. The server was set to use the suPHP handler on my php 7.4 version and I changed it to fcgi, since that was the handler PHP 5.6 was using. Fixed the issue! Hopefully this helps anyone else with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Redirects are usually handled in your .htaccess file.

It is possible that your htaccess file has some rule in it that is causing issues for you.

Go into your FTP server, navigate to your main WordPress folder and find the htaccess file (you might have to enable the option to view hidden files. In Filezilla you do this by clicking on Server in the top menu, then clicking on Force showing hidden files.). Back up your htaccess file by downloading it, then making a copy of your file.

Open the htaccess file you downloaded and delete everything except for this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this recently, after having scrapped through each and every tutorial and forum I could not find the real answer to my problem.
A simple WordPress file zipping, installing a fresh pack of WordPress and replacing all the new files fixed the problem.

Decided to write an article about it.
https://surveyor-jr.tech/fix-too-many-redirects-on-wordpress/